# Transferring SQL Server data via e-mail automatically every day

Tags: sql-server, database, email

We need to be able to get copies of a single row from multiple databases based in a remote area via E-Mail and then able to import the database into another SQL Server so the stats can be viewed at the end of every day by clients. The only permission we have to do this is by E-Mail as it is the clients wishes, we have tried over and over to get the client to allow us more access to doing a transfer, but they won't budge one bit. Any help would be great!

Comment: Email is really not the ideal "media" to use. I can insist with the client to give up permissions to do it work by replication or service broker showing we can rely on it for the sake of security. Anyway how much data do you need to handle that way? Gigabytes/hour? Ill not latency be a issue? What he ill permit you to do at that server at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, our client will only stick with using E-Mail to do so, if we didn't need to use E-Mail we would of been able to do this in a flash. But the data is minimal, it is 1 row of 100 numbers with the time and date onto them. It is automatically updated once an hour.

Comment: You can edit your question since a few rows hardly qualifies as "get a copy of the SQL Database". That sounds like you are getting a lot more data and metadata. By the way email can handle it (not the most secure and reliable way to do it, sure). First thing to put in mind is that emails can arrive unordered (ok, unlikely to happen with a 1 hour bettween subsequents mails, but be prepared) its a good practice to put somekind of sequence info in that emails.

Comment: Okay, all in all the data might be bigger, as this info is going to be pulled from 15 different SQL Servers based around the world, and to add to that, using a satellite link for the internet connection as they are currently in the Ocean. So I understand that the E-Mails will (most likely) be retrieved in the wrong order. How is this done then?

Comment: As @jean said, you should edit your question to put those new info. It will help you to get a more appropriate answer. And for your problem I would create an webservice and a client to each of your costumers. It would be more secure and fail-proof than email.

Comment: As stated before, the client will not change their mind, they will only stick with E-Mail for the connection between us and the servers. We have tried to talk them into allowing us more access but no good, they are sticking with a E-Mail only solution.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is in place at your clients? Express Edition?

Comment: Sure, you ill need a server time-stamp and sequence field in that emails. And as Jorge commented it makes sense to create a service to receive it from that servers (a simple job can pull it from each server) and put that messages in a queue to be processed in the right order. Also to make it reliable you ill need to handle errors, faulty messages, etc and that is a bit headache.

Comment: @SQLhint.com all of the servers are using SQL 2008 Express.

Comment: I have done this before with SQL Mail in SQL Server 2000.  DB Mail (in SQL Server 2005+) is more reliable and easier, but it can only send, not receive.  Not sure if 2008 express still supports SQL Mail either.

Comment: You do know that SQL has built in tools to do what you are trying to hack together, right?

Comment: Doesn't matter now, I have set up a SMTP Relay on the server, now what I will need to do is set some tasks to export to an xml every hour and overwrite the current .xml file, then after that I will set the task to send that file every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [sp_send_dbmail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

You can use it to send the output from an arbitrary SQL query as an email attachment.  Your clients can save the attachment and use it to bulk insert into their DB

Comment: DB Mail can send but it cannot receive.

Comment: Answering how to automate the receiving side requires much more information about the clients' infrastructures.  Since the clients are at sea with a satellite uplink, it's hard to make assumptions as to what they have on hand.